# How to get Program Files Path in Visual Studio configuration

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/tomaznunittests.aspx) tutorial to make NUnit tests debugable in Visual Studio. In the debugging options I set "Start external program:" to C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.4.8\bin\nunit-x86.exe.
Is there a way to get the program files directory dynamically to avoid problems when other people work with this solution on their system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable $PROGRAMFILES holds this. Most properties in visual studio allow you to use environment variable expansion like this: "$(PROGRAMFILES)\NUnit 2.4.8\"

Comment: I had already tried this. The problem was that I had used the IDE instead of manipulating the *.csproj.user file directly. But now it works as it should.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

%ProgamFiles% if using in a Windows path.